# Schaum's Outlines for self-study

Tags: physics, advice, learning

I wish to learn Physics via self-study. I realize that I have a long way to go as far as Mathematics prerequisites: I will need to begin with Precalculus(I took that course many years ago, so I am quite rusty, and I am aware that , at minimum, I will need Multi-variable Calculus.

Would the Schaum's Outlines be sufficient for Mathematics preparation? (I am seriously considering Schaum's, as the series provides lots of solved problems and is the most economical way to go).

Question #2: Would you also recommend the "Demystified" series (Precalculus, Calculus, Advanced Calculus)for me?

Comment: Schaum's is probably a really good source of problems (which you'll need!), but it will definitely be insufficient in explaining the harder concepts you haven't seen before. If you don't want to supplement with a textbook, you could watch the relevant lectures from the Khan academy free online when needed. I haven't watched them to know if they are good, but there are a ton of topics ... and it's free.

Answer (score 2):

Schaum's is excellent.  In many cases (not all) it can replace a textbook.  It can definitely replace a textbook if you are reviewing something you have already learned (not your case here).